# Plotting baseball pitches as qualitative variable by color

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I was thinking of doing this in R but am new to it and would appreciate any help

I have a dataset (pitches) of baseball pitches identified by 
'pitchNumber' and  'outcome' e.g S = swinging strike, B = ball, H= hit 
etc.

e.g. 
    1 B ;
    2 H ;
    3 S ;
    4 S ;
    5 X ;
    6 H; etc.

All I want to do is have a graph that plots them in a line cf  BHSSXB 
but replacing the letter with a small bar  colored to represent the letter, with a legend, and optionally having the pitch number above the color . Somewhat like a sparkline.

Any suggestion on how to implement this much appreciated

Comment: Ditto what @Bitbert3 said. What does `X` stand for by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base graphics idea from which to work. First some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
baseball <- data.frame(pitchNumber = seq_len(50),
                       outcome = factor(sample(c("B","H","S","S","X","H"), 
                                               50, replace = TRUE)))
> head(baseball)
  pitchNumber outcome
1           1       H
2           2       S
3           3       S
4           4       H
5           5       H
6           6       H
```

Next we define the colours we want:

```
## better colours - like ggplot for the cool kids
##cols <- c("red","green","blue","yellow")
cols <- head(hcl(seq(from = 0, to = 360,
                    length.out = nlevels(with(baseball, outcome)) + 1), 
                 l = 65, c = 100), -1)
```

then plot the `pitchNumber` as a height 1 *histogram-like* bar (`type = "h"`), suppressing the normal axes, and we add on points to the tops of the bars to help visualisation:

```
with(baseball, plot(pitchNumber, y = rep(1, length(pitchNumber)), type = "h", 
                    ylim = c(0, 1.2), col = cols[outcome],
                    ylab = "", xlab = "Pitch", axes = FALSE, lwd = 2))
with(baseball, points(pitchNumber, y = rep(1, length(pitchNumber)), pch = 16, 
                      col = cols[outcome]))
```

Add on the x-axis and the plot frame, plus a legend:

```
axis(side = 1)
box()
## note: this assumes that the levels are in alphabetical order B,H,S,X...
legend("topleft", legend = c("Ball","Hit","Swinging Strike","X??"), lty = 1,
       pch = 16, col = cols, bty = "n", ncol = 2, lwd = 2)
```

Gives this:

[image: baseball sparkline]

Comment: Gavin, thanks so much for this. I should be able to adapt it from this to have breaks for pitcher and each batter - hopefully anyways. One thing I did not understand was the 'nr' in the points section. When I replaced it with length(pitchNumber) I was able to replicate your work exactly. Also is there a way to just plot the points - or make the histogram height about that small level. If I use pch15 for the points category that produces pretty much what I am after

Comment: I have made some progress on this but would appreciate further expertise in a couple of areas. I am now using real data with an SQL query

Comment: baseball <- sqlQuery(channel,paste(
"select outcome,  pitcher,
row_number() over(order by atBatID) as pitchNumber
from tblAtBats
where matchid = 1  and pitcher = 'A'"
));    So this provides me with the graph for one pitcher in the game. I would like to gave separate lines and a label for each pitcher A,B,C etc.  Also I would like to set a xlim = c(1,50) and have any pitches in excess of 50 by any one pitcher start on a new line. Finally, I have set axis(side = 3) to get the axis at the top. I woud like to use the Hmisc library to set tick marks but cannot see how to set them on a top axis

Answer (score 4):

And the same graph using `ggplot`.

Data courtesy of @GavinSimpson.

```
ggplot(baseball, aes(x=pitchNumber, y=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, colour=outcome)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_linerange() +
    ylab(NULL) +
    xlab(NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 1)) +
    opts(
        panel.background=theme_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(),
        axis.text.y = theme_blank()
    )
```

[image]

Comment: +1, I like the use of `opts` to change the look and feel of the standard ggplot output.

Answer (score 3):

This is in response to your last comment on @Gavin's answer. I'm going to build off of the data provided by @Gavin and the ggplot2 plot by @Andrie. `ggplot()` supports the concept of faceting by a variable or variables. Here you want to facet by pitcher and at the pitch limit of 50 per row. We'll create a new variable that corresponds to each row we want to plot separately. The equivalent code in base graphics would entail adjusting `mfrow` or `mfcol` in `par()` and calling separate plots for each group of data.

```
#150 pitches represents a somewhat typical 9 inning game. 
#Thanks to Gavin for sample data.
longGame <- rbind(baseball, baseball, baseball)
#Starter goes 95 pitches, middle relief throws 35, closer comes in for 20 and the glory
longGame$pitcher <- c(rep("S", 95), rep("M", 35), rep("C",20))
#Adjust pitchNumber accordingly
longGame$pitchNumber <- c(1:95, 1:35, 1:20)
#We want to show 50 pitches at a time, so will combine the pitcher name 
#with which set of pitches this is
longGame$facet <- with(longGame, paste(pitcher, ceiling(pitchNumber / 50), sep = ""))
#Create the x-axis in increments of 1-50, by pitcher
longGame <- ddply(longGame, "facet", transform, pitchFacet = rep(1:50, 5)[1:length(facet)])
#Convert facet to factor in the right order
longGame$facet <- factor(longGame$facet, levels = c("S1", "S2", "M1", "C1"))

#Thanks to Andrie for ggplot2 function. I change the x-axis and add a facet_wrap
ggplot(longGame, aes(x=pitchFacet, y=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, colour=outcome)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_linerange() +
    facet_wrap(~facet, ncol = 1) +
    ylab(NULL) +
    xlab(NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 1)) +
    opts(
        panel.background=theme_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(),
        axis.text.y = theme_blank()
    )
```

You can obviously change the labels for the facet variable, but the above code will produce:

[image]